# Cannot access OWA internally using external DNS name

Tags: exchange-2010

Exchange 2010, all Exchange roles on same server. Recently had to renew UCC cert, and was forced to remove all netbios names from it. Now, i'm getting cert warnings internally in Outlook. I've created a zone on the internal DNS servers for domain.com, since the AD domain is domain.local.

I've changed the internal uri for each service (owa, ecp, eas and oab) to all be https://mail.domain.com/[service].

I've checked everything I can think of, pinging mail.domain.com returns the private IP of the server, as expected. I know thats whats causing my Outlook cert mismatch error, because in the cert its saying its looking for server.domain.local, which is no longer valid in the cert.

I'm thinking this lies with Exchange and not IIS, but i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Double check Your dns records if Your zone created on internal DNS servers is correct. check internally if ping server.domain.local and ping mail.domain.com returns same IP address ?

Comment: Look in my last paragraph, DNS resolution is fine.

Comment: so I would double check IIS bindings.